# Deployment of R-program in shiny not working

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, shinyapps

I did a sample app in R and it is working fine in R-studio. I managed to deploy the code successfully into `www.shinyapps.io`. After deployment the app link is not working. It is hang-up by "please wait" for long time then show error "disconnected from server". Could anyone please help me with this.
ui.r

```
library(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

head(recommendation)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)
server <- function(input, output) { }

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard")  
#Sidebar content of the dashboard
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Visit-us", icon = icon("send",lib='glyphicon'), 
             href = "https://www.salesforce.com")
  )
)

frow1 <- fluidRow(
  valueBoxOutput("value1")
  ,valueBoxOutput("value2")
  ,valueBoxOutput("value3")
)
frow2 <- fluidRow( 
  box(
    title = "Revenue per Account"
    ,status = "primary"
    ,solidHeader = TRUE 
    ,collapsible = TRUE 
    ,plotOutput("revenuebyPrd", height = "300px")
  )
  ,box(
    title = "Revenue per Product"
    ,status = "primary"
    ,solidHeader = TRUE 
    ,collapsible = TRUE 
    ,plotOutput("revenuebyRegion", height = "300px")
  ) 
)
# combine the two fluid rows to make the body
body <- dashboardBody(frow1, frow2)
ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'This is my Page title', header, sidebar, body, skin='red')
shinyApp(ui, server)

library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='', token='', secret='')
deployApp(appName="myApp")
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
  #some data manipulation to derive the values of KPI boxes
  total.revenue <- sum(recommendation$Revenue)
  sales.account <- recommendation %>% group_by(Account) %>% summarise(value = sum(Revenue)) %>% filter(value==max(value))
  prof.prod <- recommendation %>% group_by(Product) %>% summarise(value = sum(Revenue)) %>% filter(value==max(value))
  #creating the valueBoxOutput content
  output$value1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      formatC(sales.account$value, format="d", big.mark=',')
      ,paste('Top Account:',sales.account$Account)
      ,icon = icon("stats",lib='glyphicon')
      ,color = "purple")  
  })
  output$value2 <- renderValueBox({ 
    valueBox(
      formatC(total.revenue, format="d", big.mark=',')
      ,'Total Expected Revenue'
      ,icon = icon("gbp",lib='glyphicon')
      ,color = "green")  
  })
  output$value3 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      formatC(prof.prod$value, format="d", big.mark=',')
      ,paste('Top Product:',prof.prod$Product)
      ,icon = icon("menu-hamburger",lib='glyphicon')
      ,color = "yellow")   
  })
  #creating the plotOutput content
  output$revenuebyPrd <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = recommendation, 
           aes(x=Product, y=Revenue, fill=factor(Region))) + 
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + ylab("Revenue (in Euros)") + 
      xlab("Product") + theme(legend.position="bottom" 
                              ,plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold")) + 
      ggtitle("Revenue by Product") + labs(fill = "Region")
  })
  output$revenuebyRegion <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = recommendation, 
           aes(x=Account, y=Revenue, fill=factor(Region))) + 
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + ylab("Revenue (in Euros)") + 
      xlab("Account") + theme(legend.position="bottom" 
                              ,plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold")) + 
      ggtitle("Revenue by Region") + labs(fill = "Region")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Log file is not showing any error. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seams to me that you are not incorporating your server code in the app that you are deploying. No reference to the server.R file and there is a server function already defined with no contents

Comment: Why do you have calls for `shinyApp(ui, server)` both in server.R and ui.R?